# Проблема с локалью в Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, locale

Изучая модуль **locale** в Python , столкнулся с проблемой использования его методов.

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "de_DE")          

number = 12345.6789
formatted = locale.format("%2f", number)
print(formatted)
```

Должно вывестись следующее: `12345.67`

Но вместо этого выводится сообщение об ошибке:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "training.py", line 2, in
>   
>       locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'de_DE')   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/locale.py", line 604, in setlocale
>       return _setlocale(category, locale) locale.Error: unsupported locale setting

Как мне решить эту проблему?

Comment: Значит в системе не установлена локаль de_DE.

Comment: Необходимо предварительно установить нужную локаль согласно инструкции для вашей операционной системы. И возможно ещё требуется указание кодировки de_DE.UTF-8

Comment: @andreymal , я использовал `pip3 install locale' , но ничего не вышло

Comment: @MickeyU настройка локали в операционной системе не имеет никакого отношения ни к pip, ни к python. Обратитесь к документации вашей ОС

Comment: Из доступного:
`C , 
en_US.utf8, POSIX, 
ru_RU.utf8`

Comment: вы можете привести в вопросе вывод следующих команд в shell: `locale`, `locale -a | grep de_DE` ?

Comment: @MaxU 
`LANG=ru_RU.utf8
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.utf8"
LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.utf8"
LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ALL=`

Comment: @MaxU , ну а для второго пусто

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547631/python-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting)

Answer (score 2):

```py
import locale

# для  Windows
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "de")      

# для MacOS
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "de_DE")
```

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста ещё раз вопрос. Как ваше сообщение отвечает на него?

Comment: @0xdb, предположу что ответ заключается в том, что автор вопроса использует маковский вариант названия локали на винде.

Comment: @Qwertiy Мало, что под вопросами надо хрустальный шар крутить, теперь ещё под ответами)) По моему, нужно просто удалить этот ответ, какая от него польза.

Comment: @0xdb, надо всегда иметь запас хрустальных шаров ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy всегда держу в запасе, но бывают дни, заканчиваются уже к обеду.

Answer (score 0):

```
formatted = locale.format("%.2f", number)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. и вообще, как изложенное вами отвечает на вопрос.